# Find last column and row

Tags: excel, vba, autofilter

Can someone please explain how to read the below code ? I undersatand that here we are looking for the last column and row, but it is not clear to me.

```
Set plage = .Range("a1:a" & .Cells.Find("*", , , , xlByRows, xlPrevious).Row)
```

and

```
plage.Offset(1).Resize(plage.Rows.Count - 1).EntireRow.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Delete
```

Answer (score 2):

This

```
.Cells.Find("*", , , , xlByRows, xlPrevious).Row
```

uses the [Range.Find method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.find) and looks into all cells `.Cells` of the entire worksheet and tries to find `"*"` which means find anything. `xlByRows` is the search order, it means search by row, and `xlPrevious` is the search direction means search backwards.

So it tries to find in all cells of the sheet row wise backwards starting from the end of the sheet anything that is not empty. This will end up in the last used cell of the sheet and `.Row` returns the row number of that cell.

```
Set plage = .Range("a1:a" & .Cells.Find("*", , , , xlByRows, xlPrevious).Row)
```

So `plage` is then the range starting from A1 until the last used row.

```
plage.Offset(1).Resize(plage.Rows.Count - 1).EntireRow.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Delete
```

Then `.Offset(1)` will offset from that range by 1 row. If plage was `A1:A10` after the offset it is `A2:A11`. Then `.Resize(plage.Rows.Count - 1)` will resize it by 1 row less than `plage` has rows making it `A2:A10`. The purpose of all this is to remove the header row from this range.
Finally `.EntireRow` makes it the entire rows so rows 2 to 10 `2:10` and `.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)` will take only the visible cells of that range and `.Delete` them.

---

The entire code looks a bit over complicate to me and you could reach the exact same actually easier.

```
Set plage = .Range("2:" & .Cells.Find("*", , , , xlByRows, xlPrevious).Row)
```

This will make `plage` directly `2:10` without having to use entire rows, offset and resize, so you just need to take the vibible cells from that and delete them.

```
plage.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Delete
```

Note that `SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)` might throw an error if there are no visible cells. So I recommend to do some error handling:

```
Dim CellsToDelete As Range
On Error Resume Next  ' hide all error messages because the next line might throw an error
Set CellsToDelete = plage.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
On Error Goto 0  ' re-enable error reporting!

If Not CellsToDelete Is Nothing Then
    CellsToDelete.Delete
Else
    MsgBox "There are no visible cells to delete.", vbInformation
End If
```

Answer (score 1):

### Find and AutoFilter

- Just addressing some minor issues.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub FindAutoFilter()
    
    Dim plage As Range
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
        ' The 'Find' method may (will) fail if the worksheet is filtered
        '.AutoFilterMode = False
        Dim lCell As Range
        ' xlFormulas will allow hidden rows, xlValues may fail.
        Set lCell = .Cells.Find("*", , xlFormulas, , xlByRows, xlPrevious)
        If lCell Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
        Set plage = .Range("A1:A" & lCell.Row)
    End With
    
    ' e.g.:
    plage.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="Delete"
    ' The following makes sense only with the previous. Note the slight
    ' inaccuracy: in this case you should first resize, then offset.
    plage.Resize(plage.Rows.Count - 1).Offset(1) _
        .EntireRow.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Delete

End Sub
```

Comment: This has still a "minor" issue. If the filter returns no visible cells it will still throw an error.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ: That's a major issue and would fit better in your answer.